# How to turn table registers into columns of a temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table **product** and a table **orders** which uses table 'products' to specify what was the *product* sold in each *order*.

Now I want to make a report to export to Excel, where each product is in a different column and each one of them have register counting how many product sold and needed to sell, one register per seller.

Example:

product:

```
 id | desc    | target_per_month
 -------------------------------
 1  | prepaid | 1000
 2  | pospaid | 500
```

orders:

```
 id | seller  | product_id | date
 --------------------------------------
 1  | clark   | 1          | 2014-12-11
 2  | kent    | 1          | 2014-12-10
 3  | kent    | 2          | 2014-12-11
 4  | kent    | 1          | 2014-12-10
 5  | clark   | 2          | 2014-12-09
```

What I want:

```
 seller | prepaid_sold | prepaid_target | prepaid_left | pospaid_sold | pospaid_target | pospaid_left 
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 clark  | 1            | 1000           | 999          | 1            | 500            | 499
 kent   | 2            | 1000           | 998          | 1            | 500            | 499
```

How would this `select` look like if I want this table to be dynamic to accept new products? The way it is now is manually put 3 columns for every new product, very terrible!

Answer (score 0):

You have a tricky one here, I believe you should try a different approach, but to answer your question I'd say that you can dynamically create the "CREATE TABLE" statement based on results of a query grouping by the terms you need. You need to create the group by query, create a cursor for it and a loop to complete the sql statement for the table creation.
Once you have the statement, you can create the table with "EXEC(@MySqlStatement)" where @MySqlStatement is a variable containing the text for the "CREATE TABLE" statement.

After that you can use the same loop to fulfill the new table with data.

Although I'm sure you can make it work with this approach, I've never tried it because of the amount of work and testing that it takes.

Another thing you need to consider is where are you going to call that t-sql script. If you build a store procedure, it will be fine but you cannot use the store procedure in excel (at least it's not straight forward). If you build a multi statement table function, possibly it won't allow you to do certain things, as these kind of functions have some limitations regarding the t-sql languaje functions you can use within.

If you want to consider another option, SSRS would be the best as it can create a matrix with all the columns you need based on your resultset, basically it does all the work for you. This report can be exported to excel.

Other option is to create a more logical resulset with the kind of rows that you currently have and transform that data within excel, by means of Pivot tables, macros,...

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use Dynamic SQL.  Start with a SELECT that gets the number of products, and then use that number to create your column list in a dynamic query.